# AWS API re-deployment using ansible

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, ansible

I have an existing API in my AWS account. Now I am trying to use ansible to redeploy api after introducing any resource policy changes.
According to AWS I need to use below CLI command to redeploy the api:

```
- name: deploy API
 command: >
   aws apigateway update-stage --region us-east-1 \
       --rest-api-id <rest-api-id> \
       --stage-name 'stage'\
       --patch-operations op='replace',path='/deploymentId',value='<deployment-id>'
```

Above, '`deploymentId`' from previous deployment will be different after every deployment that's why trying to create that as a variable so this can be automated for redeployment steps.
I can get previous deployment information using below CLI:

```
- name: Get deployment information
  command: >
   aws apigateway get-deployments \
      --rest-api-id 123454ne \
      --region us-east-1
  register: deployment_info
```

And output looks like this:

```
deployment_info.stdout_lines:
  - '{'
  - '    "items": ['
  - '        {'
  - '            "id": "abcd",'
  - '            "createdDate": 1228509116'
  - '        }'
  - '    ]'
  - '}'
```

I was using `deployment_info.items.id` as deploymentId and couldn't able to make this work. Now stuck on what can be Ansible CLI command to get `id` from output and use this id as `deploymentId` in deployment commands.
How can I use this `id` for `deploymentId` in deployment commands?

Comment: Any reason you are not using the dedicated module for it? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/aws_api_gateway_module.html

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I am updating REST API which requires redeployment. That's why didn't use ansible module. I am following this aws doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-deployments.html

Answer (score 0):

I created a small ansible module which you might find useful

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Creates a new deployment for an API GW stage
# See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-deployments.html
# Based on https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.aws/blob/main/plugins/modules/aws_api_gateway.py

# TODO needed?
# from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
# __metaclass__ = type

import json
import traceback

try:
  import botocore
except ImportError:
  pass  # Handled by AnsibleAWSModule

from ansible.module_utils.common.dict_transformations import camel_dict_to_snake_dict

from ansible_collections.amazon.aws.plugins.module_utils.core import AnsibleAWSModule
from ansible_collections.amazon.aws.plugins.module_utils.ec2 import AWSRetry


def main():
  argument_spec = dict(
    api_id=dict(type='str', required=True),
    stage=dict(type='str', required=True),
    deploy_desc=dict(type='str', required=False, default='')
  )

  module = AnsibleAWSModule(
    argument_spec=argument_spec,
    supports_check_mode=True
  )

  api_id = module.params.get('api_id')
  stage = module.params.get('stage')

  client = module.client('apigateway')

  # Update stage if not in check_mode
  deploy_response = None
  changed = False
  if not module.check_mode:
    try:
      deploy_response = create_deployment(client, api_id, **module.params)
      changed = True
    except (botocore.exceptions.ClientError, botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError) as e:
      msg = "Updating api {0}, stage {1}".format(api_id, stage)
      module.fail_json_aws(e, msg)

  exit_args = {"changed": changed, "api_deployment_response": deploy_response}
  module.exit_json(**exit_args)


retry_params = {"retries": 10, "delay": 10, "catch_extra_error_codes": ['TooManyRequestsException']}

@AWSRetry.jittered_backoff(**retry_params)
def create_deployment(client, rest_api_id, **params):
  result = client.create_deployment(
    restApiId=rest_api_id,
    stageName=params.get('stage'),
    description=params.get('deploy_desc')
  )

  return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```